# navigating between page divs with select and jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Trying to use this dropdown select to change to a different anchor on the page. It's working except that when you select SF, it goes to the SF page and the selector button is set to SF. But if you then select NY, it goes back to #page1 but the default button stays as SF, unless the page is reloaded.

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="#page1">New York, NY</option>
<option value="#SF">San Francisco, CA</option>
<option value="#LV">Las Vegas, NV</option>
<option value="#DAL">Dallas, TX</option>
</select>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I think there is incomplete information here. On the #SF anchor text, for example, it's an entirely new page with its own copy of the `<select>` in the header of that page. So what is happening is that when you select the second one to go back to the first, it doesn't reset the first one.

Here is what the second select looks like:

```
<select name="select2" id="select2" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false" ONCHANGE="window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="#SF">San Francisco, CA</option>
<option value="#page1">New York, NY</option>
<option value="#LV">Las Vegas, NV</option>
<option value="#DAL">Dallas, TX</option>
```

Here's what happens

1 - Load #page1, NYC is preselected. 
2 - Select SF, loads #SF, SF is selected because it is default in the second select
3 - Select NYC, it DOES load the NYC/#page1 page, but the select dropdown is still stuck on #SF because that was what it was last left at before the location changed.

Hopefully this more fully explains my problem. I've tried something like this (http://jsfiddle.net/QEUwg/132/) but it isn't working, maybe because the two selects are in separate divs?

OK This works:

```
//refresh value         
$('select').selectmenu('refresh');

//refresh and force rebuild
$('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

It only took about 20 hours of beating my head against the wall.

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing your case

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/meshtdagn/WUtU7/2/

Comment: Tell me something, do you want the page to change or you want to scroll to the element with that id.

Comment: I want it to scroll to that element, but when it does, I want the value in the select to match. So when it scrolls back to NY, I don't want the select to still say SF like it does now, I want it to switch back to NY.

Comment: It's still not working for me. Click SF. Works fine. But then, try clicking back to NY.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer to the solution

Comment: Ya - it's making me wait 8 hours but I will.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location` instead of `location`

#### Update:

I will give you a better way since you are already using jQuery.

```
$("#select-choice-1").change(function() {
    $($(this).val())[0].scrollIntoView(true); 
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Z6GY9/)

#### Update 2

The problem is that you are using multiple select box and not updating all of them, when you are changing the page

```
$(".navigateToPage").on('change', function() {
    $(".navigateToPage").val($(this).val()); //set value for all the select boxes
    $(".navigateToPage").parent().find(".ui-btn-text").html($(this).find("option:selected").html()); 
    //^ Also find the text and update them

});
```

#### [Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/WUtU7/8/)

Comment: Still nothing, please see my edits above to more further explain my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @krapdagn I voted to see if you get more answers. It seems like bug.

Comment: Thanks, sorry we couldn't work it out. I've been banging my head against the wall for 2 days now on this.

Comment: Got it to work - see my edited question. Can't believe this took so long.

Comment: @krapdagn, Even I got it working, but with a workaround, I have updated my `update 2`